# Free fishing for youth & seniors in Ontario — Sport or conservation license level?

Tags: fishing

> “If you are under 18 years old or 65 and older You do not need to
> purchase an Outdoors Card or licence to fish. You will need to carry
> your government-issued identification with you, that includes your
> name and date of birth, at all times while fishing. Your
> identification acts as your licence to fish, if you belong to one of
> these age ranges.”
>
> https://www.ontario.ca/page/fishing-licence-canadian-residents

What license level applies to those age groups? Sport or conservation? I ask because the limits are different for the two licenses.

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the page you linked to, in the section about veterans, it says:

> In accordance with other deemed licences, veterans and active members of the Canadian Armed Forces will need to follow the seasons, quotas and limits associated with a sport fishing licence.

This strongly suggests the "children and old people" rules give you a deemed license that is a sport one.

I found [confirmation](https://files.ontario.ca/mnrf_fishing_and_hunting_regulations_1/2019-licence-information-and-fees-english.pdf) on a government site that it is sport limits:
[image: sport limits]